# Stopping a script pasted into and running through BTT (bettertouchtool)?

Tags: mac, shortcut, script, python, bettertouchtool

I have a python script that runs continously once turned on that I can turn on with a shortcut in BTT (bettertouchtool), but once it's on, I have no way to turn it off, it's pasted into the program, is there any way to turn it off once it's on? I know you can kill from terminal .py files but it's not a .py afaik, because it's not a file.

I asked that forum btw it's tumbleweeds so I'm trying elsewhere.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean pasted into the program. If a program runs either it is expected to run all the tiome or it has a defined way to stop it.

Comment: there is no way to stop it, you set a trigger key for execute shell script/task, paste in the script, in this case a trackpad gesture is the trigger, and it starts. then the script is designed to run continuously, so i can't turn it off from inside the program, if I run it from another program there is a stop button yes, but I don't like that program it's a code editor.